# How to combine two colors with varying alpha values

Tags: colors, formula, alpha, color-blending

I have two colors, c₀ and c₁. They have variable alpha, red, green and blue values: (a₀, r₀, b₀, g₀) and (a₁, r₁, b₁, g₁). I'm wondering if there is a simple formula for combining these colors to obtain the correct new color (c₂).

Let's say that c₀ overlays c₁. I understand that if they had equal alpha values, then averaging their comparative red, green and blue values would do the trick. But when the alpha values differ, I'm noticing this doesn't work properly—it seems alpha determines the level at which each color's RGB values "contribute" to the final color.

Otherwise stated,

```
If a₀=a₁ then:
    a₂=a₀=a₁,
    r₂=(r₀+r₁)/2,
    g₂=(g₀+g₁)/2,
    b₂=(b₀+b₁)/2
Else:
    a₂=(a₀+a₁)/2,
    r₂=?,
    g₂=?,
    b₂=?
```

Comment: I believe the answer is given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030560/1528942

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alpha blending a red, blue, and green image to produce an image tinted to any rgb value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030471/alpha-blending-a-red-blue-and-green-image-to-produce-an-image-tinted-to-any-rg)

Answer (score 30):

**Short answer:**

if we want to overlay c<sub>0</sub> over c<sub>1</sub> both with some alpha then

a<sub>01</sub> = (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>

r<sub>01</sub> = ((1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub>·r<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>·r<sub>0</sub>) / a<sub>01</sub>

g<sub>01</sub> = ((1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub>·g<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>·g<sub>0</sub>) / a<sub>01</sub>

b<sub>01</sub> = ((1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub>·b<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>·b<sub>0</sub>) / a<sub>01</sub>

Note that division by a<sub>01</sub> in the formulas for the components of color. It's important.

**Long answer:**

The basic formula for the color when c<sub>0</sub> overlays opaque c<sub>1</sub> with alpha a<sub>0</sub> is

r<sub>0 over 1</sub> = (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·r<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>·r<sub>0</sub>

// the same for g & b components

So if there is another color c<sub>2</sub> and c<sub>1</sub> actually is not opaque but has an alpha a<sub>1</sub> we can overlay first c<sub>1</sub> over c<sub>2</sub> and then c<sub>0</sub> over the resulting color.

r<sub>1 over 2</sub> = (1 - a<sub>1</sub>)·r<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>·r<sub>1</sub>

r<sub>0 over (1 over 2)</sub> = (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·((1 - a<sub>1</sub>)·r<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>·r<sub>1</sub>) + a<sub>0</sub>·r<sub>0</sub>

If we had a color c<sub>01</sub> which overlays c<sub>2</sub> with the same result as overlaying first c<sub>1</sub> and then c<sub>0</sub> it would be like this:

r<sub>01 over 2</sub> = (1 - a<sub>01</sub>)·r<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>01</sub>·r<sub>01</sub>

Ok, let's make them equal:

(1 - a<sub>01</sub>)·r<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>01</sub>·r<sub>01</sub> = (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·((1 - a<sub>1</sub>)·r<sub>2</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>·r<sub>1</sub>) + a<sub>0</sub>·r<sub>0</sub>
= (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·(1 - a<sub>1</sub>)·r<sub>2</sub> + (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub>·r<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>·r<sub>0</sub>

so

1 - a<sub>01</sub> = (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·(1 - a<sub>1</sub>) = 1 - ((1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>)

a<sub>01</sub>·r<sub>01</sub> = (1 - a<sub>0</sub>)·a<sub>1</sub>·r<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>0</sub>·r<sub>0</sub>

Comment: For those who want to read more, see wikipedia's entry on alpha compositing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending

Comment: there is a question for the last formula:
if a * r + b = c * r + d，
then a = c, b = d?

I have an opposite examle:
2* 3 + 3 = 1* 3 + 6

Comment: @XuyeeWang Obviously, I took a = c and b = d because we need a * r + b = c * r + d for arbitrary value of r. But your example works only for particular r, here it's 3. If you take another value of r, e. g. 4, then 2 * 4 + 3 = 11 != 1 * 4 + 6 = 10

Answer (score 1):

This is a python function that implements the above answer when both colors have the same alpha:

```py
def mix_two_colors_with_alpha(hex_color1, hex_color2, alpha=0.5):
    """Returns a color that's equivalent to displaying input color2 
    on top of input color1 where both have the given alpha.
    """

    hex_color1 = hex_color1.lower().strip("#")
    hex_color2 = hex_color2.lower().strip("#")
    result = "#"
    for i in 0, 2, 4:
        rgb_value1 = int("0x"+hex_color1[i:i+2], 16)
        rgb_value2 = int("0x"+hex_color2[i:i+2], 16)
        # r2 over r1 = (1 - a0)·r1 + a0·r2
        new_rgb_value = int((1-alpha) * rgb_value1 + alpha * rgb_value2)
        new_rgb_hex = hex(new_rgb_value).upper()
        result += new_rgb_hex[2:]
    return result
```

Example:

```
mix_two_colors_with_alpha("#FF80BF", "#004AC0", alpha=0.4) 

returns '#996ABF'
```