# Is alpha value really necessary to show the colour?

Tags: colors, alpha

This is just a doubt which i recently got when experimenting with colours...

Normally to display a colour we give RGBA (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) values to show the colour.

Alpha value is used to make the colour transparent or to blend the colour with the colour behind the thing we want to paint.

I got this doubt that after using the alpha value and getting the colour. Is it possible to reconstruct the exact same colour with using only RGB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two colors with varying alpha values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900598/how-to-combine-two-colors-with-varying-alpha-values)

Comment: *Short answer:* Yes. Monitors doesn't know what is alpha, so somewhere the computer converts RGBA to RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can represent any color with only RGB.